# aws ec2 ssh error: `ssh: connect to host x port 22: Operation timed out`

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I'm trying to connect to a EC2 instance via SSH. When I try to connect to the instance, using `ssh -i "test.pem" ec2-user@xx.xx.xx.xx` I get the error: `ssh: connect to host xx.xx.xx.xx port 22: Operation timed out`.

**EC2 instance config**

Platform: Amazon Linux

AMI: ami-0841edc20334f9287

Instance type: t2.micro

Public IPv4: associated Elastic IPv4

**EC2 instance associated VPC subnet config:**

Route Table: (Destination - Target)

`10.0.0.0/24 - local`

`0.0.0.0/0 - igw-...`

ACL: (Type - Protocol - Port range - Source)

Inbound

`SSH - TCP - 22 - 0.0.0.0/0`

Outbound

`HTTPS - TCP - 443 - 0.0.0.0/0`

Security Groups: (Type - Protocol - Port range - Source)

Inbound

`SSH - TCP - 22 - xx.x.xxx.xxx/xx (My IP)`

Outbound

`HTTPS - TCP - 443 - 0.0.0.0/0`

**Attempts:**

1. Followed this AWS [article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-resolve-ssh-connection-errors/) (solution #3) in which they propose adding this script to the instance’s user data:

```
--//
Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"

#cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
- [scripts-user, always]

--//
Content-Type:
    text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="userdata.txt"

#!/bin/bash
iptables -F
service sshd restart
--//
```

Which resulted in the same error:
`ssh: connect to host public.ip port 22: Operation timed out`

2. Chaning ssh user:

`ssh -i "test.pem" ec2-user@public.ip`

`ssh -i "test.pem" root@public.ip`

Which resulted in the same error:
`ssh: connect to host public.ip port 22: Operation timed out`

3. I tried using my public subnet within the same VPC and I was able to connect to ec2 via ssh. When comparing the public and private subnets, the only difference was that the public subnet's NACL allowed all traffic inbound traffic.
4. Connecting with EC2 Instance Connect on the console resulted in a blank terminal window even after 10 minutes or so.

Comment: Can you telnet <vm ip> 22 ?

Comment: NACL should be the issue. can you try allowing all the traffics in the NACL. this is because the ephemeral ports should be allowed for the inbound and outbound rules.  That is usually the ports between 1024-65535. you can read more about ephemeral ports here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html#nacl-ephemeral-ports

Comment: Also in the outbound NACL, you are not allowing the ssh outgoing traffic. NACLs are stateless and you should allow the return traffic as well

Comment: @ArunK Thank you for both of your suggestions. Adding the inbound/outbound NACL rules to account for the ephemeral ports fixed the problem.

Comment: @ ArunK If you want to write up your comment as a suggested answer, I'd be more than willing to approve it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Glad to help. posted as the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your NACL has the inbound rules for ssh. you should also allow the return ssh traffic in the outbound NACL rules. Because the NACL's are stateless unlike the security groups.

In addition to that, you should also allow ephemeral port ranges for the inbound and outbound NACL rules. Ephemeral ports are random ports ranging between 1024 and 65535 that a client initiating the request chooses as the source ports.

[NACL Ephemeral Ports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html#nacl-ephemeral-ports)

Answer (score 1):

Try running the `Reachability Analyzer` in your aws console.

> AWS console >> VPC >> Network analysis >> Reachability Analyzer

You can choose the source of analyzer as internet gateway and destination as your ec2 instance. Once you run the analyzer, it will tell you if the instance is reachable from you source (IGW in this case) and the interesting thing is, it will also give you the reason why it is not reachable which will help in further debugging the cause.

Comment: **FYI:** VPC Reachability Analyzer is now located within the Network Manager console